# Mering dataframes with a twist

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge columns and perform some data analysis. 
Bellow i present the structure of the data frames that i use in Pandas.

Dataframe1
ProductID   ProductName

Dataframe2
Customer id Name

Dataframe3
OrderID Customer ID

Dataframe4
OrderID ProductID

DataframeFinal
Name    Order   ProductID   OrderID

Now i try to merge them but unfortunately i don't know how.
When i try to use merge i cannot estimate if the simple merge "do the job".

Comment: What is your question exactly? How to merge columns? If you ask a nice clear question then you're likely to get a nice clear answer

Comment: please edit your question by adding some data in order to get good help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple merge should do the job so long as you specify the `on` parameter ie:

`DataframeFinal.merge(Dataframe1, on="ProductID")`

Should give you a correctly merged DF (DataFrame) with the following columns:

Name Order ProductID OrderID ProductName

You can then continue to merge your other DFs in until you get the required DF.

Comment: Thank you, will try and post if this will help.